# Docker swarm on multiple physical machines

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, docker-swarm

I am deploying Hyperledger Fabric in a distributed environment using instructions from [here](https://wahabjawed.medium.com/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f). To achieve distributed setting **Docker Swarm** is required.

One of my node is on the remote (which is my school's server) and the `docker swarm` is already initialised and ready to accept connections.

The other node which is a local PC should join the docker swarm, to connect to this swarm I am using port forwarding like this `ssh user@xxx.x.x -L 2377:localhost:2377` but getting this error:

`Error response from daemon: Timeout was reached before node joined. The attempt to join the swarm will continue in the background. Use the "docker info" command to see the current swarm status of your node.`

After reading instructions from another group also tried multiple port forwarding like this:

`ssh user@xx.xxx -L 2377:127.0.0.1:2377 -L 7946:localhost:7946 -L 4789:localhost:4789` but still same error.

Please advise me:

1. Is this my school's firewall which is preventing me to connect? or any other reason.
2. Can port forwarding work in this situation?

Operating System:

Ubuntu 18.04 local - 16.x remote

Comment: Perhaps. Why don't you test?

Comment: I can use port forwarding for Jupyter Notebook, following same method. But my concern is this idea might not work with the Docker. How can I check this with Docker?

Comment: Check port accessibility.

Comment: `nc -zv host name 2377` -> no output - I think its not connecting with Docker port